# Вывести id через alert

Tags: javascript

Пытался сделать так, чтобы выводилось имя id **(domik)** через alert,

который я нашел и изменил ему цвет.
Но вместо этого выходит совсем другое сообщение.

```js
let find = document.getElementById('domik');
find.style.background ='blue';

alert(find);
```

```css
#domik{
background: orange; 
height:250px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 </head>              
<body>

<div id="domik">

</div>        
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: потому что в алерт вы пихаете сам элемент а не его id

Comment: а как пихнуть его id?

Comment: `alert(find.getAttribute('id'));`?

Comment: @gil9red а просто `find.id` не достаточно?

Comment: @teran, теперь знаю, что `.id` достаточно :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выбирайте какой больше нравится (возможно это даже не все способы)

```js
const find = document.getElementById('test')
alert(find.id)
alert(find.getAttribute('id'))
alert(find.attributes.id.value)
```

```html
<div id="test">Test</div>
```

Comment: Шикарно, а в чем отличие всех эти трех методов)?

Comment: При помощи ```find.id``` вы можете взять только атрибут id или даже изменить его. При помощи ```find.getAttribute('id')``` вместо id вы можете ввести любой другой атрибут к примеру ```href``` и получить его. Так же есть ```find.attributes``` c помощью которого можно легко перебрать все атрибуты и узнать их значения.

Comment: Ооо спс за инфу